# mysql UPDATE function with DATE_ADD() function

Tags: php, mysql

**Table structure:**

[image]

I encounter `DATE_ADD()` function recently while I am searching for a process of how to make a **warning in multiple fail login attempts** in php. I want to learn how to use this with `mysql UPDATE` function where, first, it sets the `current date` and then it will `add 15 minutes` (interval) so that, the user can't login in the next 15 mins.

update:

example: if the user failed to login 3 times. it will update the user's account that, he/she can log on the next 15 minutues.

this is something code that I think but not working to me

```
$sql = "UPDATE {$users} SET {$reLoginDate} = DATE_ADD({$reLoginDate}, 15 INTERVAL MINUTE) WHERE {$user} = {$username}";
```

the `$reLoginDate` is set on current time and will `DATE_ADD()` 15 minutues in advance.

Here is the image of my table: 2nd update:
[table screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI0hM.jpg)

Comment: Your description is not so clear to help us to understand your question. You have to add more details for it.

Comment: i am sorry, what it is not clear to you ? I need to learn how to use or how to make a statement `mysql UPDATE` function with `date_add` function. This is all I want to learn thanks

Comment: For example, add some sample data and your expected result if you want to find a solution for a question; if you want learn something about [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) syntax or [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function, check the manual first.

Comment: thanks I will edit it now

Comment: @10086 i updated it now! thanks again, please do check it

Comment: And what is your table? Is it named with `user`?

Comment: yes, it will search what username is trying to log in, then, it will update the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple thing, try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users
        SET reLoginDate = DATE_ADD(reLoginDate, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
        WHERE user = '$username'";
```

Comment: @upvote Sorry, my bad, updated my answer, check it again.